# How do I prevent mouse movement from waking up a suspended computer?

Tags: mouse, suspend

It's really annoying as I have to unplug the mouse after a suspend to ensure that an occasional bump doesn't wake up the system. I haven't found anything in system settings which could disable this neither by googling around.

Comment: **IMPORTANT:** Pretty much all the answers below are bad and wrong. There is something enabling the mouse wake up in the first place. *That* should be altered! Leaving the enabling be, and adding a disabling thing later, is just a really really shoddy suggestion. Doing it via a script instead of in UDEV, on UDEV systems, is even worse. … **On almost all systems, there is a toggle for this in the BIOS, that the user himself or the vendor set.** Only if you can’t turn that off, try the UDEV solution. Also, check if any other UDEV rule enables it first.

Comment: I've been using the `echo disabled > /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/power/wakeup` (or whatever - see some of the answers below) solution since 2014 on my old Thinkpads. They do not have an USB bios setting and I don't remember if UDEV was already in place that time..

Answer (score 33):

I haven't checked the BIOS yet, but I've found a solution!

Short summary: In `/proc/acpi/wakeup`, you can see which devices are currently enabled to resume from suspend. That list shows names (abbreviated) of so called "Devices". Example "PWRB" means "power button".

If you write device-names to that file, you toggle them between enabled/disabled.

I wrote [a small HowTo for disabling wakeup-by-mouse](http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1985), based on a blog where I found that info.

Comment: This sounds much better than my answer, and I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: So, this works (however, I notice in passing that just using `sudo` won't work: one has to do `sudo su` first, then echo to `/proc/acpi/wakeup`.  However, I'm wondering whether anyone has found a way to *just* disable the mouse?  I have both on my desktop connected via (wireless) USB and this will disable the wake from keyboard too.

Comment: The link is not working.

Comment: @Timo: Link not working, because our server's currently down for maintenance ;) (Up and running 24/7 for over 9 years up to now)

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20210506200750/http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1985

Comment: Doesn't work. USB not listed there others disabled and it still wakes computer.

Answer (score 26):

Thanks to all posters as the mouse wakeup is a major inconvenience and I got my answers here. I wish to add my twist to the solutions as that may help in more cases. I had to disable 3 different items in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. My devices: `EHC1, EHC2, XHCI`. The first 2 are usb2 and the 3rd a usb3 entry. Please note that although the usb transceiver for my mouse is plugged into a usb2 port and nothing is in any usb3 port, the computer will wake on mouse moves until *all 3* items are disabled.

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | sort 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
EHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
GLAN      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:08:00.0
.. ,, ..
USB7      S3    *disabled
WLAN      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
XHCI      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:07:00.0
```

To have the wakeup items disabled on every startup, you can add something like this to `/etc/rc.local` ..

```
echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

---

Test which items need to be disabled - as indicated [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=246955#p1327847) - for each of the items that were posted as `enabled` under `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | sort` by running in terminal each of the commands below and then testing if the mouse wakes the system (without the need for restart):

```sh
sudo sh -c "echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
```

(in my case the first one was enough even after testing with other USB ports)

---

If the `/etc/rc.local` file doesn't exist

According to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/919598/47206) post, run:

```sh
printf '%s\n' '#!/bin/bash' 'exit 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/rc.local
sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local
```

The file should look something like:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo XHCI > /proc/acpi/wakeup

exit 0
```

Reboot.

---

If that still doesn't work, it might be that the file `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service` is missing or not properly configured.

Test with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/rc.local start
```

and

```
sudo systemctl status rc-local
```

Following [How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd):

Create the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service
```

Then add the following content to it.

```
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save and close the file. To save a file in Nano text editor, press Ctrl+O, then press Enter to confirm. To exit the file, Press Ctrl+X.

Check all is well with no errors with:

```
sudo systemctl start rc-local.service
sudo systemctl status rc-local.service
```

Reboot to see changes.

Comment: If you don't like my edit, please let me know by flagging @cipricus and I'll post as a separate answer linked to the above.

Comment: `sudo sh -c "echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"` explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/831850/321926) the need for `sh`.

Comment: A [preachy post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471871/72988) why one should not use `rc.local`

Comment: It's too long, may you need some headers.

Comment: There is no USB. Please fix this answer. ~$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup | sort 
Device S-state   Status   Sysfs node
EXP8   S4 *disabled
IGBE   S4 *enabled   pci:0000:00:1f.6
LID   S4 *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
SLPB   S3 *enabled   platform:PNP0C0E:00
XHCI   S3 *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0

Answer (score 18):

The solution I'm using is a udev rule that disables wakeup from a particular USB device. It should be agnostic to which port the device is plugged in to.

Create `/etc/udev/rules.d/90-usb-wakeup.rules` with the following content (modify `idVendor` and `idProduct` as appropriate, see output from `lsusb` which gives the IDs in the form: `vendor:product`):

```
# Disable waking up from Logitech unified receiver
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", DRIVERS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c52b", ATTR{power/wakeup}="disabled"
```

To get it applied without rebooting:

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
   ```
2. Disconnect and reconnect the USB device.

Inspiration comes from https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/udev#Waking_from_suspend_with_USB_device

Comment: This is actually a very elegant solution. It worked for me on Fedora 36 with a slight alteration for idProduct. My G603 mouse has this receiver: **046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. Cordless Mouse Receiver**

Comment: Much better solution than all the other /proc echoing hack job answers.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was unable to put my Lenovo P14s Gen1 AMD into s2idle / modern sleep for hours. Took me ages to find out it's because of my Bolt Receiver (MX Mechanical) plugged into the docking station. This solution fixed the issue for me in a very elegant way.

Comment: The best answer.
Just to note, for me, it worked after disconnecting and reconnecting the USB device.

Comment: sudo udevadm control --reload-rules

Comment: lsusb gives the IDs in the form: **vendor:product**

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

This solution works with Ubuntu 15.10, 18.04, 20.04, 22.04

Find your mouse idProduct and idVendor by unpluging and replugging your mouse and searching  `/sys/bus/usb/devices/*` folders. Ignore links with `:` in the name. For example follow the link for `3-3` but
ignore `3-3:1.0`

Now try to read the idProduct and idVendor. For example:
`cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/7-2.3/idProduct` => `2000`,
`cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/7-2.3/idVendor` => `24ae`.

Finally I create a script in `/lib/systemd/system-sleep` directory, name it mouse-suspend.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# From lsusb: Bus 007 Device 008: ID 24ae:2000
idProduct=2000
idVendor=24ae

# Get sys device path by vendorId and productId
function find_device()
{
    local vendor=$1
    local product=$2
    vendor_files=( $(egrep --files-with-matches "$vendor" /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor) )
    for file in "${vendor_files[@]}"; do
       local dir=$(dirname "$file")
       if grep -q -P "$product" "$dir/idProduct"; then
         printf "%s\n" "$dir"
         return
       fi
    done
}

sysdev=$(find_device $idVendor $idProduct)

if [ ! -r "$sysdev/power/wakeup" ]; then
    echo $idVendor:$idProduct not found 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

case "$1" in
    enabled|disabled)
    echo $1 > "$sysdev/power/wakeup"
    ;;
    *)
    echo "$0 enabled   -- to enable the wakeup for this device"
    echo "$0 disabled  -- to disable the wakeup for this device"
    ;;
esac

grep --color=auto -H ".*" "$sysdev/power/wakeup"
exit 0
```

If it doesn't work then run `sudo chmod +x mouse-suspend.sh && ./mouse-suspend.sh enabled`

Comment: It works with Ubuntu 18.04 on my laptop.

Comment: Still works with Ubuntu 20.04 and disables only the necessary device

Comment: Thanks! I had to change `grep -P "$product" "$dir/idProduct"` to `grep -q "$product" "$dir/idProduct"` otherwise `find_device` outputs `$product\n$dir\n` causing the check after defining `sysdev` to fail.

Comment: This stopped working for me. Even after rerunning script. idProduct and IdVendor are the same. 22.04.2

Answer (score 5):

The above solution (https://askubuntu.com/a/265389/1467620) works, but it is crude and, also it disables the keyboard wake, which is actually useful.

A more granular alternative can be this:
First, we start by enumerating the USB devices connected to the system:

```bash
lsusb | sort
```

from here, it’s pretty obvious which one is the mouse:

```bash
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

then we proceed with finding where the devices are mapped to:

```bash
grep enabled /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup

/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2.6/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2.7/power/wakeup:enabled
```

Finally, to figure out which is which, we use:

```bash
dmesg | grep Logitech | grep -o -P "usb.+?\s"

usb 2-1.2.7:
```

at which point it’s pretty obvious which one needs to be disabled:

```bash
sudo sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2.7/power/wakeup"
```

note: every time you need to echo as superuser, `sh -c` is necessary, or the system will not allow redirecting to a priviliged file.

Then it’s just a matter of suspending the system and verifying that, while the mouse does not wake it, the keyboard will.

this does not survive a system reboot, so either you need to re-run the last command, or add it to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`.

This is something that has been annoying me on Ubuntu since when I installed 16.04, and probably there forever, I cannot understand why Canonical wouldn’t add this in the System Settings.

Source: https://codetrips.com/2020/03/18/ubuntu-disable-mouse-wake-from-suspend/

Comment: Worked like a charm. This solution is much cleaner than the accepted one and deserves more upvotes.

Comment: Can't Linux desktops have this in GUI? I mean, in Windows, you can do this by going to the Device Manager, open the mouse's property, and uncheck "allow wake". Why should this so complex in Linux desktops? I wish there was some sort of third-party GUI app to manage wake-up sources/devices.

Answer (score 4):

Ridiculous, but plug out, plug back in to determine the device code method is the least tedious. So:

1. **find**

```bsh
grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup | grep enabled
```

figure out the offender using plug-out-plug-in method

2. **disable**

```bsh
sudo sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/YOUR_DEVICE/power/wakeup"
```

---

inspired by this [blog post](https://codetrips.com/2020/03/18/ubuntu-disable-mouse-wake-from-suspend/)

Answer (score 3):

The solution that worked for me, was got from [here](https://codetrips.com/2020/03/18/ubuntu-disable-mouse-wake-from-suspend/).

First, we start by enumerating the USB devices connected to the system:

```
lsusb | sort
```

from here, it’s pretty obvious which one is the mouse:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
```

then we proceed with finding where the devices are mapped to:

```
grep enabled /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup

/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2.6/power/wakeup:enabled
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2.7/power/wakeup:enabled
```

Finally, to figure out which is which, we use:

```
dmesg | grep Logitech | grep -o -P "usb.+?\s"

usb 2-1.2.7:
```

at which point it’s pretty obvious which one needs to be disabled:

```sh
sudo sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2.7/power/wakeup"
```

(note: every time you need to echo as superuser, sh -c is necessary, or the system will not allow redirecting to a priviliged file).

Then it’s just a matter of suspending the system and verifying that, while the mouse does not wake it, the keyboard will.

This does not survive a system reboot, so either you need to re-run the last command, or add it to your .bashrc or .zshrc

**Run command after reboot**
Run command `sudo crontab -e`
then on a new line add `@reboot`  and the command you want to run after reboot. For example:
`@reboot sudo sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-3/power/wakeup"` Save the file and try restarting your computer. Don't add this command to your .bashrc, it may prevent your computer from booting up.

Comment: this is as complicated as all other answers here

Comment: Works fine with 22.04, but I added the line via `sudo crontab -e` with @reboot option

Comment: I'm using this solution since 2014 for a Thinkpad T510.

Comment: @PhilipRego try `sudo crontab -e` and add a startup line

Answer (score 2):

This is my step-by-step "tutorial" to make it work for you:

1. Use command `cat /proc/acpi/wakeup` to show the list of wake up devices
2. Use command `sudo sh -c "echo XXXX >/proc/acpi/wakeup"` (replace "XXXX" with your device code) to toggle the device state (enabled/disabled). Go one device at a time and try to suspend your machine and wake it up using the device you want to disable until the deserved device will not be able to wake up the machine. Don't forget to always enable back the devices that you do not want to have disabled.
3. When you find the right device create on your desktop file "acpi_wakeup" containing following code: 
   `#!/bin/sh
   printf "XXXX" > /proc/acpi/wakeup`
   (don't forget to replace "XXXX" with your device code)
4. Move or copy the file to folder `/etc/init.d/`.
   To copy the file use following command:
   `sudo cp /home/USERNAME/Desktop/acpi_wakeup /etc/init.d/acpi_wakeup`
   (replace "USERNAME" with your actual user name)
5. Make the file executable:
   `sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/acpi_wakeup`
6. Then use 'update-rc.d' to make the required symbolic links automatically in other directories:
   `sudo update-rc.d acpi_wakeup defaults`
   (it shows `WARNING: ...missing LSB tags and overrides` but it is OK. You don't need to worry about it)
7. Reboot your computer.

*Sources and further reading:*

*http://www.das-werkstatt.com/forum/werkstatt/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1985
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=814939&page=3*

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux4noobs/comments/iittqi/comment/g395cxm/). I just wrote the first line:

```sh
sudo sh -c "echo disabled > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/wakeup"
```

Now, the USB no:1 doesn't wake up the computer.

**Note:** by rebooting the system this procedure will reset and will need to be re-run.

Comment: The device 1-1 might not be what you want
https://codetrips.com/2020/03/18/ubuntu-disable-mouse-wake-from-suspend/

Comment: How are you going to rerun after reboot?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use udev rules to set the wakeup setting  automatically. For example, I create a new udev rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/99-nowakeup.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="pci|usb", ATTR{power/wakeup}=="enabled", ATTR{power/wakeup}="disabled"
```

This will prevent any pci or usb device from waking up the system. In my case, that leaves only the power button and RTC timer as ways to wake up.

Here is a way to look at all the ways the system can wake up:

```
find /sys -type f -name "wakeup" | while read a; do echo "$(cat $a) $a"; done |sort
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! It looks like your answer is technically accurate, but it would be hard to understand for someone who lacks your expertise. Can you provide more details about how these changes affect your system, and a link to any relevant documentation?  Also, is `99-nowakeup.rules` a new file you created, or an existing one that you modified? Thanks!

Comment: Effective Solution! See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/532839/352601) for detailed information.

Answer (score 1):

In Kubuntu 19.10 the `/etc/rc.local` setting stopped working for me. I first noticed this on a Manjaro KDE, and found [this solution](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-disable-mouse-wakeup/97968/2?u=cipricus), that worked there. It also works in Kubuntu 19.10, which may mean there are some changes in newer systems (whether related to the kernel or the Plasma version I don't know).

So:

```
sort /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

and look for items that are marked "enabled". Note their names (e.g EHC1,EHC2, NXUC). Then, test which of the commands like below stop the mouse from waking up the PC:

```
sudo sh -c "echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
sudo sh -c "echo NXUC > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
```

Create a folder `~/.bin`

```
mkdir ~/.bin
```

(If you prefer another location, replace that accordingly in the following  files.)

Create a systemd service. In terminal:

```
nano /etc/systemd/system/wakeup-events.service
```

With this content:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable wakeup events on startup

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash ~/.bin/wakeup-events.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save and enter password.

In terminal:

```
nano ~/.bin/wakeup-events.sh
```

with the following content:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Disable wakeup events

echo EHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo EHC2 > /proc/acpi/wakeup
echo NXUC > /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

(Replace accordingly: e.g EHC1,EHC2, NXUC).

**Don't forget:**

```
sudo systemctl enable wakeup-events
```

And `reboot`.

Answer (score 1):

For me all the above solutions only worked temporarily, that is all the changes got reset after plugging out and in the device or reboot.

Disabling the process using the `sudo sh -c "echo XXXX > /proc/acpi/wakeup"` command works well until reboot (in my case it was `sudo sh -c "echo XHC > /proc/acpi/wakeup"`), but none of the solutions above made this setting permanent. Eventually, I found a working solution here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417956/make-changes-to-proc-acpi-wakeup-permanent

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

## Short Answer:

`ls /sys/bus/usb/devices`

get all devices with the same pattern as the devices above, and make a list of command as this:

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/wakeup"
sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2/power/wakeup"
sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-7/power/wakeup"
sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-10/power/wakeup"
exit 0
```

---

## Long Descriptive Answer:

Tested in Ubuntu 22.04

A Step-by-Step to the solution:

`lsusb | sort`

This command lists all usb devices in your computer, it is only informational.
If you don't know the manufactor of your mouse, probably you'll find here.

---

`sudo ls /sys/bus/usb/devices`

Using this command you'll see all usb connectors, in my computer I see something like this:
`1-0:1.0  3-0:1.0  3-10      3-10:1.1  3-1:1.1  3-7:1.0  4-0:1.0  usb2  usb4 2-0:1.0  3-1      3-10:1.0  3-1:1.0   3-7      3-7:1.1  usb1     usb3`

---

You can see in each connector the status about suspended mode, looking inside `/sys/bus/usb/devices/{connector}/power/wakeup`, for example:

`sudo gedit /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/wakeup`

---

To make your life easier, instead of opening each file inside each folder, you can use `grep` to open all `wakeup` files to show you only files containing `enabled`.

`grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup | grep enabled`

This command shows you devices that wakeup your computer when suspended.
This command opens each file `/power/wakeup` inside all folders inside `/sys/bus/usb/devices` and lists all files containing enabled inside.

---

`grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup | grep disabled`

This command shows you devices that **doesn't wakeup** your computer when suspended.

---

If you don't know the mouse manufacturer, you can search inside messages about device driver initialization using `dmesg` command:

`sudo dmesg`

Try to find something like Mouse, if it is wireless, try to find Wireless etc.

To simplify the search, you can use `grep` utility:

`sudo dmesg | grep Mouse`
or
`sudo dmesg > drivers_initializations.txt`
`gedit ./drivers_initializations.txt`
search for Mouse

knowing what usb connector the mouse uses, you need to disable the wakeup feacture in `/sys/bus/usb/devices/{connector}/power/wakeup`

---

Now open `/sys/bus/usb/devices/{connector}/power/wakeup`
In my case it was `/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/wakeup`

Change enabled to disabled

---

Suspend your computer and move the mouse, if it works, go to the next step:

---

Now you need to include this command inside a system startup script, it doesn't work inside .bashrc .profile, because you need to use sudo, and it is before session loading.

I used `rc.local` script. It is a superuser startup script. It is called after all services are loaded.

Change `/etc/rc.local` if it exists, if doesn't exist, create it.

`sudo gedit /etc/rc.local`

add the content:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -e
sh -c "echo 'disabled' > /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-1/power/wakeup"
exit 0
```

Note the example uses connector 3-1, you need to change to your connector.

The script needs to be executable:
`sudo chmod +x /etc/rc.local`

---

Reboot and suspend your computer and check if mouse wakeups your computer, if it still wakeups, rc.local is disabled in your Systemd, go ahead and enable rc.local:

`sudo systemctl is-enabled rc-local.service`
`sudo systemctl status rc-local.service`

if it is `static` or `disabled`, then type the following commands to enable `/etc/rc.local` with systemd under Linux.

`sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service`

---

Reboot and suspend and try again.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way specific to your hardware, in which case the option may be available through your system's BIOS settings.

Getting to your BIOS menu to change settings is also system specific. Usually you press a key just after rebooting, and the key to press is often displayed on the screen.

However, user138339's answer seems like a more general way to achieve what you need, and you can do this from the running system.

Comment: @Evi1M4chine: : my old Thinkpad can't do this. In this case you need to hack. Otherwise you are correct. The correct answer should be: If you can't tweak your bios then ...

Comment: @kanehekili: There’s actually unlocked BIOSes for old Thinkpads. I ran a script that patched my BIOS and let me install any battery or expansion card I like. That script also unlocked all possible settings, safe and unsafe, in the BIOS. I just can’t stand when businesses want to treat people like children and literally domesticate them.

Answer (score 0):

This script solved my problem. check it out.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# allow only one instance
r=$(pidof -x -o $$ ssmonoff.sh)
set -- $r
if [ "${#@}" -ge 1 ]; then
    echo "Script already running. Exit..."
    exit
fi

dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | ( while read line; do
    if echo $line | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then
            xinput --set-prop "Dell Premium USB Optical Mouse" "Device Enabled" "0"
            xset dpms force off
    else
            xinput --set-prop "Dell Premium USB Optical Mouse" "Device Enabled" "1"
    fi
done )
```

All you have to do is, first, run `sudo xinput list`,
find the given Name of your USB mouse, and put it on the script.
Then, save the file as "ssmonoff.sh", make it executable, and set it to run on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Great explanation. I simply added to rc.local the following command

```sh
for d in $(cat /proc/apci/wakeup | grep enabled | grep -v PS2K | cut -b -4); do echo $d > /proc/acpi/wakeup ; done
```

to disable every device than PS2K (keyboard PS2) from wakeup.