# Logitech Mouse power saving

Tags: power-management, logitech

Is there a way to put my Logitech wireless mouse to sleep after a while? When using windows if I don't touch the mouse for something like 5 min it is turned off automatically and when I touch it again it turns on. This behavior doesn't happens using ubuntu.
I already tried with setting an auto suspend value, but this isn't what I need

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but my logitech m510 does this on ubuntu too. How do you know it does not turn off?

Comment: your mouse doesn't disconnect or disconnects?
I know because after a while when I touch the mouse it turns the led, indicating that it is now powered on and using ubuntu it never happens

Comment: My mouse lights up when moving after some time has passed.

Comment: And do you have logitech unifying receiver autosuspend enabled?

Comment: I did not change the default settings (nor do I know where I could), but i actually thought this feature is hardwired in the mouse. (Works on android too (with a usb-otg adapter))

Comment: mine never lights up. I enabled autosuspend and changed the auto suspend delay to 5 min. will check if it works

Answer (score 3):

Setting auto in /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-3/power and changing autosuspend_delay_ms to 300000 (5 min) solved it

Comment: Changing autosuspend_delay_ms worked for me. First I had to identify the correct USB device using `lsusb`. I took the last four of the product number then grepped to figure out what port matched which product.  `grep xxxx */idProduct`. Then I went into the identified folder and edited the autosuspend_delay_ms value.

Comment: I find I need to run `echo "200000" | sudo tee -a /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-5.3/power/autosuspend_delay_ms` every time I boot my computer.  @antone what did you mean by "setting auto" - I don't quite follow. Thanks!

Comment: Found it. `echo "auto" > "/sys/bus/usb/devices/usbX/power/level"` is probably what you meant. That is already set to the correct value in my case and doesn't solve my issue. It seems that setting `auto_suspend_delay_ms` can be set for all devices as a global option in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`. One can add `usbcore.autosuspend=10000" for example or -1 to fully disable it. I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to save power then use  **[jupiter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/)**
if i misinterpreted your question i suggest [go here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/mouse-movement-wakes-computer-from-suspend-how-to-disable-this).