# Kubuntu 14.04 : usb mouse movement wakes up from sleep

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, suspend, mouse

I have the following problem: when the computer is in sleep mode (S4 mode) I can wake up it with a simple movement of my USB mouse. I'd like to disable this "fast" wake up, but I have some problems.

In `/proc/acpi/wakeup` I had this:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4                                                                                                                                                                    
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC       S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
```

So, following some tutorials online (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/mouse-movement-wakes-computer-from-suspend-how-to-disable-this?rq=1)) I typed:

```
sudo -s
echo EHC1 >/proc/acpi/wakeup
echo EHC2 >/proc/acpi/wakeup
echo XHC >/proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Now the situation is:

```
RP01      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.2
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP04      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4                                                                                                                                                                    
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
GLAN      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EHC1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC       S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
```

But nothing has changed, a tiny movement of my mouse wakes up my computer.
Do you have any solution?

Comment: Try to comepletely remove the mouse from the wake up file

Comment: Could you tell me how?

Comment: well you obviously see those old *Enabled ones. You can try to remove those lines.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this in your bios.   Get into your bios {F12 or F10 usually does it during boot, possibly the delete key).  Turn off "Wake on mouse" it should be in a section called "boot" or "power".  I can't give you specifics since all bios are a bit different.