# Mouse movement wakes computer from suspend, can't disable it

Tags: 14.04, mouse, suspend, wakeup

When my laptop goes to suspend, a slight mouse movement wakes my laptop up. This is bad when I am packing my pc into my bag and accidentally move my mouse. PC stays up during the ride consuming battery. So there is already this topic but it did not help: [previously asked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/mouse-movement-wakes-computer-from-suspend-how-to-disable-this)

I made sure all usb devices are disabled to wake up:

```
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
LID   S4    *enabled 
SLPB      S3    *enabled 
IGBE      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:19.0
EXP2      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.1
XHCI      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
EHC1      S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
```

by echoing to the /proc/acpi/wakeup the device names EHC1 and XHCI in /etc/rc.local

Also I have identified the device with lsusb and made sure

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-6/power/wakeup
```

returned disabled.

I don't know how else I can disable it. I am using Lenovo T450s with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Thanks!

Edit: I am using Fujitsu wireless mouse WI610.

Comment: Can't you turn off the mouse when not using it?  Or, if it has a USB receiver, remove that before moving.  Not very high tech, but it is what it is.

Comment: duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/mouse-movement-wakes-computer-from-suspend-how-to-disable-this

Comment: Ah, sorry, retracted my vote.

Comment: Thanks Marty, yes that is a workaround. But this in 2016 with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS this should not be any issue! Besides, very often I forget to remove the tiny USB wireless dongle from my laptop, especially when I am in hurry.

Comment: Hi @ScottStensland , I have already mentioned that question. But none of the solutions there helped me.

Answer (score 3):

On my Ubuntu 16.04 x64 ASUS ZenBook UX430UA works the following:

```
# Check
more /proc/acpi/wakeup
or
grep --color -E '|enabled'  /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
```

and then disable routine

```
# Disable
for f in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
do
   echo "disabled" > $f
done
```

In order to disable after reboot, add disable routine into /etc/rc.local before exit 0 line.