# Moving the USB mouse cause the laptop to wake up from sleep

Tags: 14.04, mouse, wakeup

I bought a wireless mouse and keyboard (Dell) .It's working fine but after I suspend my laptop, movement of the mouse (but not the touchpad) causes the laptop to wake up. Why does this happen and how do I choose to turn it off or on?

Comment: Check wake on usb option in bios.

Comment: And if there's no "Wake on USB" option in the BIOS, you may need to just unplug the mouse.

Comment: No, there is no wakeonusb in my BIOS settings.

Comment: @JonasCz I need to use the mouse. It works perfectly fine but this is just something out of the blue.

Comment: I mean unplug it before / after you suspend the laptop, and then plug it in again when you need it.

Comment: @JonasCz but that is a physical solution. I desperately want to know why it happens.

Comment: It happens because the BIOS is written to do this. The manufacturer of the laptop thought this "feature" would be helpful. But usually, there _is_ a way to turn it off. What is the model of your laptop ? Maybe there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Samsung 300e4a. There was nothing in the BIOS about waking up.

Comment: That's because it's not an option, they just made it that way. If it's a wireless mouse, there should be a power switch. So turn off mouse, put computer to sleep, done.

Comment: @Dorian I recently learned screen mirroring, it was just perfect. The only problem was I couldn't wake my computer from sleep "wirelessly". I tried everything I could nothing worked. This thing shows that there is a way and I basically need help finding it out.

Comment: Duplicate / with answers is here - https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/how-do-i-prevent-mouse-movement-from-waking-up-a-suspended-computer#265389