# What is the sh -c command?

Tags: sh

I discovered the `sh -c` command. I found it before I posted here but I can't find any posts from Google that explain it, so I would like to know what it is and what its complete syntax is.

Comment: The reason that you didn't find anything posted on Google was because of the Minus(-) Sign. Adding '-' before a word in a query will tell a Google to ignore pages that use that word prominently. try  `sh "-c"`

Comment: I use [duckduckgo.com](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22sh+-c%22&atb=v92-6__&ia=web) when Google doesn't help me finding programming answers

Answer (score 69):

`sh` calls the program `sh` as interpreter and the `-c` flag means execute the following command as interpreted by this program.

In Ubuntu, `sh` is usually symlinked to `/bin/dash`, meaning that if you execute a command with `sh -c` the dash shell will be used to execute the command instead of bash. The shell called with `sh` depends on the symlink - you can find out with `readlink -e $(which sh)`. You should use `sh -c` when you want to execute a command specifically with that shell instead of bash.

You can use this syntax (the `-c` flag) with other interpreters too. One classic use of it (pointed out by @edwinksl is to [get around the problem of redirection not working with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82256/how-do-i-use-sudo-to-redirect-output-to-a-location-i-dont-have-permission-to-wr) (here you could use `bash -c` or `sh -c`)

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "foo" > /home/bar'
```

will write the file `bar` containing the text `foo` to `/home/`, while `sudo echo "foo" > /home/bar` fails [as explained very well here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/230476/when-using-sudo-with-redirection-i-get-permission-denied)

It's important to use 'single quotes' around the command string, otherwise the current shell will try to expand it before it's passed to the interpreter you called. For example with `python`:

```
$ python3 -c print (35/7)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
$ python3 -c 'print (35/7)'
5.0
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how to use `sh -c`? Would be extra nice if it demonstrates the assignment of positional parameters that are mentioned in the `-c` part of `man sh`.

Comment: Here, single quotes are not used, but doubles: `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/master/tools/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 33):

The `-c` argument is:

> Read commands from the command_string operand instead of from the
>   standard input.  Special parameter 0 will be set from the command_name
>   operand and the positional parameters ($1, $2, etc.)  set from the
>   remaining argument operands.

Other details of the `sh` arugments can be found by running:

```
$ man sh
```

An example of using a string as an argument is:

```
$ sh -c "echo This is a test string"
```

This is a more detailed `sh -c` example.  It will download a document from Google Drive and open it up for editing on the desktop:

```
$ sh -c "wget 'https://docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/1jcBtdlMx0f4BhCmAmnIViIy4WN4oRevWFRzse-P00j0/export?format=docx' -O test.docx && xdg-open test.docx 2>/dev/null"
```

Comment: That answer is in the most simple manner explains the use of `-c` parameter - simply changing the input source for `sh` command from stdin to the input argument of string type.

Answer (score 20):

`sh -c` spawns a *non-login*, *non-interactive* session of `sh` (`dash` in Ubuntu).

The command following that will be run in that shell session, it will be treated as argument (positional parameter) 0 (`ARGV0`), and the remaining portion as the argument to that command (`ARGV0`), starting from 1 (`ARGV1`, `ARGV2`, ...).

You can also use typical shell features allowed to run in this kind of session e.g. command separation using `;` to use multiple commands, command grouping using `{}`, spawn another subshell with `()`, and so on. Usage of these can slightly change the argument definitions/examples mentioned earlier.

---

Just to note, the features that are specific to *interactive* shells only (by default), e.g. history expansion, `source`-ing of `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` etc will not be available in this session as it is *non-interactive*. You can simulate an interactive sessions behavior (almost), by using the `-i` option:

```
sh -ic ...
```

Similarly, the features that are specific to *login* shells only (by default) e.g. `source`-ing of `~/.profile` (given `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` do not exist) and `/etc/profile` will not be done as the shell is a *non-login* shell. You can simulate login-shells behavior using the `-l` option:

```
sh -lc ...
```

To simulate both login and interactive sessions:

```
sh -lic ...
```

Comment: +1 *"sh -c spawns a non-login, non-interactive session of sh"*