# curl, sh, what do those commands mean?

Tags: command-line, curl, sh, atom, echo

I've been wandering in the web and saw this about how to install atom, the new text editor:

```
$ curl -sL https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
```

I just wanted to know what these commands are actually doing. What does `curl` do ?

I also read `sh` was about running some shell instance but for what, what does this command make possible for instance, and what does it do specifically here?

Comment: Why the downvote? Appart from "what do curl do" (OP could easily figure out by himself), I think this is a valid question. I rather think it's very good if beginners want to know what they are copy-pasting from the internet, and we should not discourage that by downvoting.

Comment: @RoVo I didn't downvote, but the tooltip for the downvote says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", and this question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: @wjandrea lol that's partly true but the sh -c command still was quite tough to understand don't you find? When you understand nothing that's hard to understand any part you know.

Comment: [How can I get help on terminal commands?](https://askubuntu.com/q/991946/507051)

Comment: sh man were pretty long, so am I a gambler

Comment: @UgaUga Yeah, it's three layers of commands deep, and it's got a lot going on apart from that too. There are some existing related questions ([What is the sh -c command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/831847/301745), [How do I add a line to my /etc/apt/sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/q/197564/301745)), but they're hard to find unless you know what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CURL

Like the [homepage](https://curl.haxx.se/) says, `curl` is a

> command line tool and library for transferring data with URLs

Greatly simplyfing, it allows you to download a file from a (web)server.

You could get the same result by opening `https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey` with a browser and then saving the displayed file to disk.

#### SH

Running `sh` **opens** a new shell. The way it's used here is to *execute* a list of commands (via the `-c` flag) in a *new* shell with root privileges (the `sudo` part).

The `sh -c` part is needed because of the redirection (`> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list`). As the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list` needs root privileges to be written to, you cannot simply do `sudo echo ... > file`, as the redirection doesn't "inherit" privileges from the `sudo` part. You have to wrap the whole `echo` + `>` it in a new shell instance. It's somewhat equivalent to these separate steps:

1. `sudo sh` to open a new shell with root privileges;
2. `echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list` to write the new line to the `atom.list` file;
3. `exit` to go back to your normal user shell.

Comment: ok! so it runs another shell in order to override the redirection restriction of 'echo', now I understand more this kind of 'wrapping' and the reason we do this, that was unusual for me! thank you. =)

Answer (score 4):

```
$ curl -sL https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey | sudo apt-key add -
```

This is actually two commands.

`curl -sL https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/gpgkey` downloads the GPG key from PackageCLoud for the Atom Editor repository.

`sudo apt-key add -` adds it to `apt` so it can recognize and validate the repository's GPG signatures on packages.

---

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'
```

Easier if we split it into its three constituent parts.

`sudo` executes the `sh` command as superuser.

`sh -c` indicates to execute a specific command in the `sh` shell.

`'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any/ any main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list'` is the command being run by `sh -c` which creates the separate repository entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list` so that when you do `sudo apt update` it'll check that repository for package data.

Answer (score 0):

For the beginers:

1. sh (shell) is a command interpreter program. Like Bash "Bourne Again SHell" is the GNU Project's shell.
2. curl or cURL is a computer software project providing a library and command-line tool for transferring data using various protocols. The cURL project produces two products, libcurl and cURL. It was first released in 1997. The name stands for "Client URL".