# Somehow my Ubuntu wakes up from suspend on its own with lid closed

Tags: suspend

I got Ubuntu 14.04 installed on Dell Inspiron 5521. When I close the lid it falls asleep. Often when later I pass by it I notice that its LEDs indicate it's awake. Indeed it is awaken when I check.

I double checked that mouse movements and clicks cannot wake the beast up. What else awakes it? Is enslaved by FBI or NSA?

I don't have wired LAN, and only my notebook and my smartphone in WiFi LAN.

```
$ sudo journalctl | grep systemd 
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-journal[25572]: Allowing runtime journal files to grow to 78.5M.
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-udevd[127]: starting version 204
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-udevd[494]: starting version 204
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-hostnamed[4590]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-hostnamed[26523]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-hostnamed[1537]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-hostnamed[10422]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
нояб. 05 13:55:03 anima systemd-journal[25572]: Journal started
```

Comment: WOL (Wake-up on LAN) is a suitable hypotheses.

Comment: But who emits it? And how it goes through my router?

Comment: do you have an external mouse connected? - if so: https://askubuntu.com/a/378563/47206

Comment: Yes, I got a wireless mouse connected with usb mouse adapter.

Comment: I've applied the solution from "Desktop wakes from suspend at random (14.04)" question. Now waiting if the notebook wakes up