# Suspend not working in Ubuntu 18.04 and 19.04

Tags: suspend

When I tried to suspend by holding mouse on shutdown icon, it goes to suspend for 2 secs and comes to back to previous state again. Though I upgraded to 19.04 Ubuntu, issue still appears.

Comment: what options have you configured in the BIOS of your motherboard?

Comment: i dont think i made any changes related to this since my first installation of ubuntu 18.x

Comment: what I mean is do you have options like "wake up from network" enabled?

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I solved using the procedure explained here: [Ubuntu 18.04.2 immediately wakes up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133919/ubuntu-18-04-2-immediately-wakes-up-from-suspend).

Practically there is a device that has the ability to wake up the computer.
In my case it was the Bluetooth and WiFi card.

Using these two commands (when the computer is not connected to the dock) you can see if there is a device with that ability and which device it is:

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup

$ ll /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
```

The first command gives you a list of **enabled** and **disabled** that corresponds to the devices listed by the second command.

Then you can investigate which device is using

```
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/idVendor
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/idProduct
```

(You need to replace 1-4 with the concerned device).

In this way you will get two codes idVendor (in my case 8087) and idProduct (in my case 0025) that you can google to see what it is.

At the end you can disable it with:

```
# echo "disabled" >  /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-4/power/wakeup
```

I hope that can help you too.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and for your interest in this site.  While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes or is deleted.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I modified the answer, I hope it is more useful now.

Comment: Thanks buddy helped me. To just extend it, I wrote a script and placed it in the etc/init.d  i.e startup directory.   bash -c 'echo "disabled" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.1/power/wakeup'
bash -c 'echo "disabled" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.2/power/wakeup'

Comment: superb ..helpful..it's working

Comment: `sudo echo "disabled" >  /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-7/power/wakeup`
`bash: /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-7/power/wakeup: Permission denied` and when i open the file it says `[ Error writing lock file /sys/bus/usb/devices/1-7/power/.wakeup.swp: Permission denied ]`

Answer (score 2):

This is just a summary of Stefan's answer, in the form of runnable code.

Maybe someone could provide a more readable version; the awk part is hideous.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/power/wakeup
do
    [ $(cat $file) = "enabled" ] || continue

    device=${file%/power/wakeup}
    vendor=$(cat $device/idVendor) || continue
    product=$(cat $device/idProduct) || continue
    verror="### name for vendor '$vendor' not found ###"
    perror="### name for product '$product' not found ###"

    curl -s http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids -o - | awk '
        /^'$vendor' / { e=$0; print ""; print; next }
        /^[^[:space:]]/ { if (e) { print "'"$perror"'"; exit } }
        /^[[:space:]]+'$product'/ { if (e) print $0; exit }
        END { if (!e) print "'"$verror"'" }
    '
    read -p "Disable wakeup by this device? [y|N] " yn
    case "${yn:-n}" in
        [yY]) echo "disabled" > $file ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: I keep getting access denied on it. any idea how I can use sudo here?

Comment: I used `su -i` in Ubuntu 22.04 to switch over to root and it worked great

Answer (score 1):

Fix in my case (Ubuntu 19.10) was to enable **Automatic screen lock** in:

> Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock

Without *Automatic screen lock* ON, the system would suspend/shutdown for few seconds, and then it would wake up (power up) into an unknown state - unusable.

I am not sure if this is a feature, or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

I can not post a comment to the last answer by ADz but the exact opposite worked for me.

I had this problem where after hitting suspend, the system would shut down the screen for a second, turn off wifi and bluetooth and then do nothing. After 30 seconds it would go back to normal.

Per ADz's instructions, I intended to **enable Automatic screen lock** and I discovered it was already on. Then, I **disabled it** and lo and behold that did it. It now sleeps instantly as normal.

```
Settings -> Privacy -> Screen Lock -> DISABLE Automatic Screen Lock
```

My system is an HP Envy 13 that always had some issue on sleeping but after a kernel upgrade stopped going into sleep altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS, I installed dconf editor and changed this to false:

```
/org/mate/desktop/lockdown/disable-lock-screen
```

Comment: You're using Ubuntu Mate, not the standard Ubuntu, and you should install all updates ASAP.

Comment: I am using gnome, @ChanganAuto

Comment: I see sub-folders like gmone, mate, and yorba in the org folder, but the above change worked for me - @ChanganAuto