# AMD Desktop immediately wakes up from sleep

Tags: 20.04, suspend, power-management

I recently installed a new motherboard, a Gigabyte B450 Aorus Elite, and since then I've been unable to put my computer to sleep without it immediately starting up again. I had this problem with my last motherboard as well, an Asus Prime B450-Plus, but I was able to solve it last time by disabling certain devices in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. This time, however, even if every single device is disabled, it still immediately wakes up.

[I tried this solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133919/ubuntu-18-04-2-immediately-wakes-up-from-suspend), but the only device that was enabled was the keyboard, which I wanted to use to wake up the computer from sleep. Nevertheless, I disabled it, but it still immediately wakes up.

`pm-is-supported --suspend` returns 0, the BIOS doesn't appear to have any settings that would alter this (I disabled Wake-On-LAN just in case but that didn't help), I unplugged all my devices except for a keyboard, mouse, and display but that didn't do any good either. I'm at my wit's end here.

Using Kubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try disabling the WiFi, or pulling out the Ethernet cable? I'm having the same problems, sometimes.

Comment: This had no effect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

0

Had the same problem, it has nothing to do with /proc/acpi/wakeup, I disabled all without result

The problem was my new Lenovo monitor, I disabled the auto-switching of the source of the monitor, Now the monitor is running with HDMI only and my (K)Ubuntu 21.10 keeps in power-save
Maybe somebody can explain it to me :)

Comment: Sadly, my BenQ GW2270H monitor doesn't have this function, as far as I can tell. In any case, I only have the one input plugged into it anyway, so.