# Computer Refuses to Sleep

Tags: nvidia, kernel, network-manager, bluetooth, suspend

OS:  Ubuntu 22.10
Graphics:  Nvidia GeForce GTX1060

```
uname -a                                                                
Linux 5.19.0-31-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Jan 20 15:20:08 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After reading through all possible solutions:

- [Ubuntu 18.04.2 immediately wakes up from suspend](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1133919/ubuntu-18-04-2-immediately-wakes-up-from-suspend)
- [Ubuntu wakes up after few seconds of sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598236/ubuntu-wakes-up-after-few-seconds-of-sleep)
- [laptop fails to suspend or hibernate (wakes up after 2-5 seconds without user interaction)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449871/laptop-fails-to-suspend-or-hibernate-wakes-up-after-2-5-seconds-without-user-in)
- [How do I prevent immediate wake up from suspend and/or hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148481/how-do-i-prevent-immediate-wake-up-from-suspend-and-or-hibernation)

My computer still wakes up immediately after being suspended.

I tried disabling EHC1, EHC2, XHC but it didn't do much so I left it as enabled.  Below is just to show what else is waking up my PC.

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup                                                                     INT ✘ 
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
PEG0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:01.0
PEGP      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PS2K      S4    *disabled
PS2M      S4    *disabled
RP01      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP02      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP03      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP05      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP06      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP07      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP08      S4    *disabled
PXSX      S4    *disabled
RP04      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.3
GLAN      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:19.0
EHC1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1d.0
EHC2      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1a.0
XHC       S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
```

I checked for any USB devices that wake up my computer but they're all disabled.

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb*/power/wakeup                                                    
disabled
disabled
disabled
disabled
```

I also enabled nvidia-suspend.service, nvidia-resume.service, and nvidia-hibernate.service using systemctl but it still came on after suspension.

I checked every line in /var/log/syslog but I couldn't find what triggered it.  I can see the computer went into sleep mode.  All CPU Cores went offline and all of the sudden, ACPI PM started Low-Level Resume.  Any idea where I should look to fix this issue?  I didn't check syslog in Fedora but the same behavior also happened on the same machine before I switched to Ubuntu.  This leads me to suspect there's a single common problem, Nvidia Graphic Card driver.  Any help is much appreciated.

```
Feb 22 21:12:30 ModemManager[911]: <info>  [sleep-monitor-systemd] system is about to suspend
Feb 22 21:12:30 NetworkManager[896]: <info>  [1677129150.6844] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Feb 22 21:12:30 NetworkManager[896]: <info>  [1677129150.6846] device (wlp5s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Feb 22 21:12:30 google-chrome.desktop[4025]: [4019:4049:0222/211230.686636:ERROR:connection_factory_impl.cc(472)] ConnectionHandler failed with net error: -2
Feb 22 21:12:30 NetworkManager[896]: <info>  [1677129150.6924] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Feb 22 21:12:30 wpa_supplicant[897]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 22 21:12:30 gnome-shell[2219]: Timelines with detached actors are not supported. <unnamed>[<Gjs_ui_panel_QuickSettings>:0x562f87160150] in animation of duration 150ms but not on stage.
Feb 22 21:12:30 wpa_supplicant[897]: wlp5s0: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
Feb 22 21:12:30 wpa_supplicant[897]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp5s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Feb 22 21:12:33 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Feb 22 21:12:33 systemd[1]: Starting Record successful boot for GRUB...
Feb 22 21:12:33 systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA system suspend actions...
Feb 22 21:12:33 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Feb 22 21:12:33 logger[5140]: <13>Feb 22 21:12:33 suspend: nvidia-suspend.service
Feb 22 21:12:33 systemd[1]: grub-common.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 22 21:12:39 systemd[1]: nvidia-suspend.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 22 21:12:39 systemd[1]: Finished NVIDIA system suspend actions.
Feb 22 21:12:39 systemd[1]: Starting System Suspend...
Feb 22 21:12:39 systemd-sleep[5162]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Feb 22 21:12:39 kernel: [ 2783.804635] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.812686] Filesystems sync: 0.008 seconds
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.812834] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.814707] OOM killer disabled.
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.814708] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.815648] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.816460] e1000e: EEE TX LPI TIMER: 00000011
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.899582] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2783.899766] sd 4:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.332643] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.411604] ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.472026] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.472027] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.472028] ACPI: PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.472104] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.473541] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.475271] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.476872] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.478743] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.480462] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.481951] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.483436] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.485913] ACPI: PM: Low-level resume complete
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.485930] ACPI: EC: EC started
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.485931] ACPI: PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.486265] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.486304] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.486305] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.490345] CPU1 is up
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.494432] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2784.496254] CPU2 is up
...
...
...
Feb 22 21:12:51 systemd-resolved[792]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Feb 22 21:12:51 systemd[1]: fwupd-refresh.service: Deactivated successfully.
Feb 22 21:12:51 systemd[1]: Finished Refresh fwupd metadata and update motd.
Feb 22 21:12:51 systemd-sleep[5162]: System returned from sleep state.
Feb 22 21:12:51 bluetoothd[832]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
Feb 22 21:12:51 kernel: [ 2790.922660] PM: suspend exit
Feb 22 21:12:51 systemd-sleep[5306]: /dev/sda:
Feb 22 21:12:51 systemd-sleep[5306]:  setting Advanced Power Management level to 0xfe (254)
Feb 22 21:12:51 systemd-sleep[5306]:  APM_level#011= 254
Feb 22 21:13:17 kernel: [ 2816.299694] watchdog: BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 26s! [nvidia-sleep.sh:5286]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem for a lot of time. Apparently in my case I had conflicting configuration files.

When doing:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
```

I could see a list of packages that I was not using marked with `rc` in the first column.

After removing them with the following command the computer started to suspend correctly:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | awk '/^rc/ { print $2 }')
```

I hope it helps.