# Ubuntu 20.04 configure laptop to wake up from keyboard or trackpad?

Tags: keyboard, suspend, touchpad, system76

I have a System76 Galaga Pro laptop running Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. When it suspends due to inactivity (like sitting with the lid open), I have to press the power button in order to wake it. I would much prefer to be able to wake it with the built in keyboard and/or trackpad. Been searching here and with Google for a solution and so far coming up empty.

Comment: Does the keyboard appear in the output of `lsusb`? If so, you’ll need to tweak the power profile of the USB bus to ensure it doesn’t completely power off when the system suspends itself 

Comment: You basically want the reverse of this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/how-do-i-prevent-mouse-movement-from-waking-up-a-suspended-computer

Answer (score 0):

System76 replied to my request for help and sent me a link for installing their drivers in Ubuntu and now my laptop wakes from the built-in keyboard.