# Prevent mouse wake up when using combo receiver

Tags: usb, suspend, mouse, logitech, wakeup

I have a mouse-keyboard combo, so they use the same USB receiver (Logitech non unifying).

Is there a method to prevent mouse wake up (from sleep), but keep keyboard wake up? At least to decrease the sensitivity?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I prevent mouse movement from waking up a suspended computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/252743/how-do-i-prevent-mouse-movement-from-waking-up-a-suspended-computer)